# how to usage ffmpeg laravel project on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, server, shared-hosting

i want to use ffmpeg on my laravel project but local file system is ok, shared hosting ffmpeg path not allowed. Should i use ffmpeg static file and how to set file path.
thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Download static files: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Upload to host, example: /your_path/ffmpeg

For use it:

```php
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
  'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/your_path/ffmpeg/ffmpeg',
  'ffprobe.binaries' => '/your_path/ffmpeg/ffprobe',
]);
```